# How can I add control to my embed audio?

Tags: html, audio, web, controls

I added some music to my website that starts when you load it. I also want to give the option to pause/unpause it. What must I do to add control?

```html
<embed controls autostart="true" height="0" loop="true" src="URL://music-file" width="0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use HTML5

A simple way to achieve this is, to use HTML5 and it's audio tag.

```
<audio controls autoplay>
       <source src="MP3 PATH" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: @JakaUrh Do you see the "Your browser does not support the audio element." text? What URL are you inserting as the src?

Comment: No it doesn't show that text... The control bar is there but it can't be used. I used http://picosong.com/EuCh. (star wars theme).

Comment: @JakaUrh Of course, if you give it that url, it will try and play that html page, not the audio. Download the audio file and set the apth to that as the src.

Comment: It works fully now, thank you... But the only problem is, that when I transfer the files to a different pc I will have to change the path name... Is there and way to set the path so it will find the mp3, no matter where?

Comment: @JakaUrh Depends. If the path name is not absolute, (ie. doesn't start from linux root or a windows drive letter, then  not). Other way is to make the path relative to the file from where you are playing it (eg music/sound.mp3 if the music folder is in the same folder as the .html file) Mark answer as accepted aswell, please.